# meshlabserver coredumps when saving ply mesh with textcoords (vt) as obj

Tags: meshlab

I have a simple mesh (a triangular surface) in ply format. It is as simple as it gets: 3 vertexes (xyz, rgb) and 1 face (vertex indicies, textcoords). I also have a texture map in a png file (parametr_tex_script.png). Here is the ply:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment VCGLIB generated
comment TextureFile parametr_tex_script.png
element vertex 3
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
element face 1
property list uchar int vertex_indices
property list uchar float texcoord
end_header
0 0 0 255 0 0
1 0 1 255 0 0
2 1 0 255 0 0
3 0 1 2 6 1 1 0 1 0 0
```

What I need to do is to convert it to obj format with texture coordinates (vt). I can do this fine using MehsLab GUI using "export mesh as", but I need to do this using meshlab server. When I run this command

> meshlab.meshlabserver -i parametr_out_ascii.ply -o parametr.obj -m vc
>   fc vt

I get core dump with the following error message:

> Opening a file with extention ply Mesh
>   /home/ilya/MeshTests/simplifications/testScript4Triangle/parametr_out_ascii.ply
>   loaded has 3 vn 1 fn output mesh 
>   /home/ilya/MeshTests/simplifications/testScript4Triangle/parametr.obj
>   meshlabserver:
>   ../../../../vcglib/vcg/simplex/vertex/component_ocf.h:386:
>   vcg::vertex::TexCoordOcf::TexCoordType&
>   vcg::vertex::TexCoordOcf::T() [with A = vcg::TexCoord2;
>   TT = vcg::Arity8,
>   vcg::vertex::InfoOcf, vcg::vertex::Coord3m, vcg::vertex::BitFlags,
>   vcg::vertex::Normal3m, vcg::vertex::Qualityf, vcg::vertex::Color4b,
>   vcg::vertex::VFAdjOcf, vcg::vertex::MarkOcf>;
>   vcg::vertex::TexCoordOcf::TexCoordType =
>   vcg::TexCoord2]: Assertion `(*this).Base().TexCoordEnabled'
>   failed. vertex color, face color, vertex tex coords, Aborted (core
>   dumped)

If I omit vt (vertex texture coords), I don't get the error, but I obviously need vt entries in the obj file.

I am suing Ubuntu 16.04. I am not sure how to get version of meshlab server, but here is the version of MeshLab gui:

> Meshlab_64bit_fp v2016.12 (built on Mar 7 2017).

Does anyone have any suggestions/workarounds on how to get obj file with vt entries? Is it a mashlab server bug? Is there another tool I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use `wt` instead of `vt`.

Comment: This resolved my issue in Meshlab 64bit_fp v2016.12 (built on Dec 23 2016)